Creating fully qualified column name in jooq/java
I am getting null with below syntax
 public static final Field<String> COLUMN=field(name("myid"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR)
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
 public static final Table<?> TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA = table("common",TABLE_NAME);
 public static final Field<String> MY_FIELD=TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA.field(COLUMN);

What am I doing incorrectly here? When I run the code MY_FIELD comes out as null

As per the Fields.field(Field) Javadoc:

Get a field known to this type by unqualified name, or null if no field is known to this type by this name.

The Fields.field() method isn't used to create new references, but to look up existing (known) references from a Table. Your table("common") instance is just a plain SQL template. It has no knowledge about its structure. Note that passing TABLE_NAME to it has no effect, as you're just passing a "bind value" to a template that doesn't expect bind values.
If you want to work with qualified names, always use DSL.name() as you did with COLUMN, e.g.:
Table<?> TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA = table(name("common", TABLE_NAME));
Field<String> MY_FIELD = field(name("common", TABLE_NAME, "myid"), VARCHAR);

If your underlying question is about reusing qualified name prefixes, then you can use the Name API for this, e.g.:
Table<?> TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA = table(name("common", TABLE_NAME));
Field<String> MY_FIELD = field(
    TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA.getQualifiedName().append("myid"), 
    VARCHAR
);

A note on using code generation
Unless your schema is really dynamic, please do consider using the code generator. Working with these identifier based tables / fields gets very cumbersome and is useful only when the schema is unknown at compile time. Otherwise, code generation greatly simplifies your life and allows for many use-cases that aren't available otherwise (e.g. implicit joins).
